# Checkbox value not getting submitted in Controller - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**My Controller Action Method is like below:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $IsActive = $request->input('IsActive');
    echo $IsActive;
    die();
}
```

**My View is like below**

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'DepartmentController@store')) !!}
     {!! Form::checkbox('IsActive', 0, null, array('class' => "flat")) !!}
     {!! Form::submit('Save', array('class' => "btn btn-success"))!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Problem**

> On Form submit, I always get value = 0 for CheckBox. Am I missing
>   something ?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `0` as value on form submit is because, you have explicitly declared value as `0`. Replace `0` with whatever value you want, and you will get the result as per your desire.

From the [api source code](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.1/src/FormBuilder.php):

```
/**
 * Create a checkbox input field.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @param  bool    $checked
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return string
 */
public function checkbox($name, $value = 1, $checked = null, $options = array())
{
    return $this->checkable('checkbox', $name, $value, $checked, $options);
}

/**
 * Create a checkable input field.
 *
 * @param  string $type
 * @param  string $name
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  bool   $checked
 * @param  array  $options
 *
 * @return string
 */
 protected function checkable($type, $name, $value, $checked, $options)
 {
     $checked = $this->getCheckedState($type, $name, $value, $checked);
     if ($checked) {
        $options['checked'] = 'checked';
     }
     return $this->input($type, $name, $value, $options);
}
```

Hope this helps you out.